# MySQLにリモート接続できない

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, network, unix

MySQLにリモート接続できません。
AWSのlightsailのインスタンス（Ubuntu14.04.5）を2つ運用しており、その一方からもう一方への接続を試みています。
MySQLのバージョンは、どちらも5.6.35です。

最終的に行いたいのはレプリケーションで、レプリケーションのスレーブ側MySQLログには

> Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'hoge@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306' -
>   retry-time: 60  retries: 37, Error_code: 2003

が出ているのですが、それ以前に、単に

```
mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u hoge
```

としても、以下のエラーで接続できない状況です。

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
>   (110)

telnetでも

```
telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 3306
```

が

> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

と、接続できないため、ポート周りかと思うのですが、原因・対策がわかりません。

行ったことは以下の通りです。
MySQLユーザhogeの接続許可設定確認
（hogeは、`grant replication slave on *.* to hoge@'%' identified by 'password';`で作成したもの。）

```
mysql> select user, host from mysql.user;
+-------------+------------------+
| user        | host             |
+-------------+------------------+
| repl        | %                |
| root        | 127.0.0.1        |
| root        | ::1              |
| root        | ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xx |
| rails_admin | localhost        |
| root        | localhost        |
+-------------+------------------+
```

my.cnfのbind-accessのコメントアウト

```
# bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

ファイアウォールの確認

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

$ sudo ip6tables -nv -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

ポートの確認

```
$ sudo netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29604/
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:21            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      595/vsftpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      901/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29604/
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      29139/mysqld.bin
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      901/sshd
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 受け口のMySQLで`show variables like 'port';`を実行して何番が出ますか？デフォルトの3306であるならfirewalldでタスクかポート番号で穴を開けてやればいいのでは？

Comment: `netstat -tlpn`の出力を見ると、IPv4アドレスのポート3306でLISTENしてないように見えます(IPv6の3306だけある)。`bind-address`はコメントアウトしたとのことですが、別の設定ファイル、あるいは起動オプションで「`::`」と指定されてないでしょうか?

Answer (score 2):

サーバー側がポートをLISTENしていないとすると、クライアントのエラーは `Connection refused` になるはずです。`Connection timed out` になるということは、ネットワークまわりの問題（ファイアウォールやルーティング等）だと思います。

スレーブからサーバーに対して ping が通るかどうか。

ping が通ったとしたら 3306 以外のポート(22番等)に接続できるかどうか。

クライアント側のファイアウォールも確認した方がいいかもしれません。